# Integer property without Required property is still required

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm not applying any [Required] attribute validation on the integer property. But every time I post the form it fired Validation. Initially it was using HTML 5 data attribute on client side. I've set ClientValidationEnabled to false in Web.config. After that it is firing Required attribute validation. 
I've created a new project but same situation. Tried to change .Net framework from 4.6 to 4.5 but no success. Also tried VS2015 and VS 2013
Client side razor code

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Weight)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Weight, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Weight", Value = "" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Weight, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save" />
}
```

Model:

```js
    public class RegistrationModel
    {
        public int Weight { get; set; }
    }
```

Action Method

```js
    public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new RegistrationModel();
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(RegistrationModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }

            return View();
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the `model` code if possible and what all other properties you have in model and view?

Comment: You don't need to apply a `[Required]` attribute to a property which is `int` - its required by default (it must have a value). If you are posting pack a `null` (empty string) value for `Weight` then you will always get a validation error. If you want it to be nullable, then you need to make it `public int? Weight { get; set; }`

Comment: And never attempt to set the `value` attribute when using the html helpers (as you are doing with `new { Value = "" }`)

Comment: Show your Model code and action method

Comment: @Hiba I've just edited my question. But Stephen Muecke comment is right. This is default behavior of integer type property.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke yes your are right about nullable property. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model property is typeof `int`. An `int` must always have a value (its not nullable) so irrespective of disabling client side validation, as soon as you hit the controller, `ModelState` will be invalid if you submit a `null` (empty string) value for `Weight`.

If you want to allow nulls, then you must make the property nullable

```
public int? Weight { get; set; }
```

Side note: You should never attempt to set the `value` attribute when you are using the html helpers to bind to your model properties.

Comment: excuse me, i'm not sure that here MODEL is showing any data annotation of required for validation. can you explain me?

Comment: @stephen how about if property in primary key? it can not be nullable

Comment: @Hiba, No a PK field cannot be nullable so you would not do this for a PK property (nor would you want to - if a malicious user tried to post a `null` value for a PK property, you would want `ModelState` to be invalid)

Comment: it happens sometime int property is PK and it happens in case of add new one. So i recommend ModelState.Remove("Weight"); 
But your answer is correct as well

Comment: @Hiba, You should not use hacks like `ModelState.Remove()` If its a PK, then the property will be `int` (not nullable) and the default will be `0` if its a new object (and it will never be editable in the view. In any case, if your creating a new object, you should be using a view model which will not even have a property if the PK so it can never be invalid.

Comment: I have faced the that problem in which my PK field is 0 and hidden and model state says the field is required even there is no validation on this field.

Comment: @Hiba, Thats impossible (unless you have done something else to cause the value to be posted as `null` and if that is the case, best to fix that problem)

Comment: value was not null it is 0. This is another discussion. Nice to talk with you

Comment: @Hiba you can share your code with us. So we can try to figure out your code issue.

Comment: Ok, hope so you have resolved your issue by using some hack (ModelState.Remove ()). Happy Coding !

Answer (score 2):

This is default behavior of integer type property because int has to 
have a value even zero.So, you have to make it of type nullable int in the model.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you,

```
<form method="post" action="/foo" novalidate>...</form>
```

or

```
<form>
    <input type="email"/> <!-- Will be validated -->
    <input type="string" formnovalidate/> <!-- Will not be validated -->
</form>
```

Comment: In your case we are by passing the validation. But in some case maybe I needed the validation :)

Comment: so you can explicitly restrict validation for particular control as mentioned in second case i.e <input type="string" formnovalidate/> <!-- Will not be validated -->